# Is there a workaround for the Aela the Huntress gets stuck in the Underforge praying bug?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My elf is married to Aela and has already completed the Companion main-quest line.

Afterwards, I decided to do some of the remaining Companion quests but after completing "The Totems of Hircine", Aela stays in the Underforge praying. I tell her to follow me, she agrees, only to strictly go to the totem again, and prays. Damn zealot.

UPDATE: 2nd item, same old problem. This time my own workaround did not work for some reason. I hence unchecked my own answer and looking for a more specific solution if there is any.

Comment: Have you tried fast travel?

Comment: I did and it did not help. Aela remains in the Underforge throughout even if she agreed to be my follower.

Comment: The same bug keeps happening to me also and everything I have looked up about this doesnt work so if anyone had another solution to this problem I would gladly appreciate it I have the PC version of skyrim so if there is a console command to fix this then that would be great

Comment: @Fappybobjoe In case you're still looking, I have added an answer that might fix it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found one myself. I wanted to give Aela some self-crafted items and so I took some of her old stuff and gave her new weapons, apparel and enchanted rings -- and afterwards she did not want to run back to the totem. It goes without saying that I instantly left the Underforge, and heureka, she was at my side again behaving normally.

Fashion and shiny things. Beats religion anytime. I should have known :)

UPDATE: The second time, I could solve it by commanding Aela to go to the entry of the Underforge. Then I told her to follow me, and left the Underforge. You can see if it's working if she doesn't try to run back to the totem. If she stays on the spot after you tell her to follow you, everything is fine again.

Comment: Women. Always after the glamour.. :P

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the fix in k0pernikus's answer didn't work for me. However, for those using a PC, I did get her to follow me using the `moveto player` command.

First, have her as a follower. Then open the console with ` while targeting Aela and click the mouse button to select her. Walk out of the Underforge and fast-travel somewhere far away (in my case it was the Labyrinth). Once there, you can use the console command `moveto player` to spawn Aela next to you. Not being able to walk to the Underforge, she will now follow you again.

Afterwards I tested if loading the Underforge would make her get stuck again. Luckily, fast-travelling to Whiterun and entering the Underforge will not make her leave your side again.

Answer (score 1):

I'm on Xbox 360, so here's how I had to do it.  Have a lot of health/healing ability and be a dual-casting master illusionist.  Have her as a follower, take away her bow and give her a cheap sword. Then punch her enough times to get her to attack you (heal yourself as needed).  Go through the front exit so you are outside of Jorrvaskr... she should follow you out and continue to attack you.  Lead her off a good ways (I even took her out of the front gate of Whiterun).  Dual-cast Calm on her and immediately talk to her and have her re-join you.  Test her compliance by drawing a weapon or spell (she should do likewise, not just stand there - if she doesn't draw, restart the process).  Once she's drawn a weapon, fast-travel to another location.  I went to Lakeview Manor and immediately spoke to her to make her my Steward.  Now she's staying with me and I can take her on as a follower again and when I dismiss her, she returns to Lakeview Manor.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution: place totem then immediately wait 24 hours